# Is there a faster/shorter way of doing these tests in C++ instead of using "if"?

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
...
int x;

int z1 = '-';
int z2 = '-';
int z3 = '-';
int z4 = 'a';

if ((z1 == 'a' || z1 == 'b')) x++;
 else if ((z1 == '-' && z2 == 'a' || z2 == 'b')) x++;
  else if ((z1 == '-' && z2 == '-' && z3 == 'a' || z3 == 'b')) x++;
   else if ((z1 == '-' && z2 == '-' && z3 == '-' && z4 == 'a' || z4 == 'b')) x++;
 else x = 0;

printf("x=%d\n",x);
...
```

My code is much longer than this, and I'm wondering if there is a shorter way to get the same results or a faster way for the program to execute it!
Thanks in advance for your help and attention!

Comment: what are you trying to do? parse something?

Comment: You could probably use a macro.

Comment: FWIW, it's a pretty simple regex. `(-?){3}(a|b)` I wouldn't exactly call it faster, but it would be one or two clear lines.

Comment: I don't think you need `z1,z2,z3,z4` just one `char * z1` is enough.. looks like you don't use loops so you repeating lots of redundant code

Comment: @BryanChen I'm trying to attribute a value to an int according to the int's which have a relation to it, and according to the value those int have.

Comment: @SSpoke z2 and the others might get a value later!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the code shorter (and more readable, extendable, and all-around better), put the `z` variables in an array and then loop over it. The below solution will remain the same number of lines for any number of `z` variables you want to have. Just adjust the size of the array.

```c++
int z[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (z[i] != '-')
    {
        x += (z[i] == 'a' || z[i] == 'b'); // note the implicit conversion from boolean to int
        break;
    }
}
```

Note you still need to account for the last index being a `-` and `x` never being incremented or set to `0`, but that can be done with a simple modification. I suggest putting the above into it's own evaluation function and than you can simply have a catch all `return`.

**Note:** You should probably be using the `char` datatype for your variables since you are specifically storing characters in them.

In terms of speed, this solution is probably equivalent if not better than your current solution. It will branch just as many times as your `if-else` statements but will probably have better branch prediction during run-time (thanks to the `for-loop`) and will evaluate less expressions.

Comment: It doesn't make it _faster/shorter_. It makes it more readable.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay It does in fact make it shorter, note the OP stated his if-statements are much longer than 4, my solution has the exact same number of lines for 4 or 400. It is also quicker since the program does not need to re-evaluate the same variables that the OP references in the original cascading if-statements.

Comment: In the worst case, OP's code consists of 14 condition checks. In the worst case, your code consists of 12 condition checks plus a `break`. Plus the overhead due to the loop. It doesn't make it any faster I guess. And as for shorter I don't think it is. The loop runs 4 times in the worst case. It is more readable, yes.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay There is no inherent "overhead" for a loop. A loop uses branches which has just as much overhead as a branch in an if-statement. Also I believe by "shorter" the OP meant length of code. If I were to have used the same code formatting style he did, my code is only 8 lines while the original is 9, and that's just his  shrunken down example.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the nice piece of code! It also helps to avoid errors! The '-' is a kind of NULL and I need it for displaying matters. Actually all 'z*' are already arrays (the top level of each [0]), but I can point a new `int y[4] ={z1[0],z2[0],z3[0],z4[0]};`. One question, can I add an specific test to a particular int within the loop by using `x += (z[i] == 'a' || z[i] == 'b'|| z[0] == 'c'|| z[0] == 'd');`?

Comment: @hehe_br That will compile but I can't tell you if it will "work" without knowing exactly what you want it to do. For that, we'd need to carry on this conversation somewhere else. Regardless, I recommend keeping index specific logic separate from the loop. Otherwise the code could still loop over the entire array `y` before finally checking the specific index, which in this case is index 0 and would have prevented the cost of the loop in the first place.

Comment: @Daniel, I will make some more tests! Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2):

You can make it faster by using `switch` statements.

```
switch (z1)
{
   case 'a':
   case 'b':
      x++;
      break;

   case '-':
      switch ( z2 )
      {
         case 'a':
         case 'b':
            x++;
            break;

         case '-':
            x += (z3 == 'a' || z3 == 'b');
            x += (z3 == '-' && z4 == 'a' || z4 == 'b');
            break;

      }
      break;

   default:
      x = 0;
}
```

Comment: This idea will bloat the code more than the OPs original method already did. I don't see how it's any faster either.

Comment: @Daniel, I looked at the assembly code generated by the code from the OP and the code I suggested. The assembly code from the OP has a few more `cmp` instructions than the assembly code from by suggested code. Those are from gcc 4.7.3 running on a Linux machine. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @RSahu thanks for your reply, it is fast but in my code it gets much longer. In your code if z3 and z4 is equal to 'a' or 'b' it is adding 2 for x when should be 1 if the first is true, I repeated the statement from z2 for them and then it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can do simething like this:

```
int main(void) {
    int x;
    char z[5] = "---a";

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (z[i] == 'a' || z[i] == 'b') { x++; break; }
        else if (z[i] != '-') { x = 0; break; }
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I actually need that as int, and your code worked making such change!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips to optimize your code (runs faster)

++x is more faster way to increment x than x++. (Refer : [Avoid Postfix Increment Operator](http://www.idinews.com/peeves/prefixIncr.html))

If you are using GNU C, you can use unlikely/likely macros to optimize your if statement. To use those macros efficiently, you have know which if statements are going to be executed more often.

If you are using windows, you can use [_assume()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b3fsfxw%28VS.80%29.aspx). But this function is not recommended to use because it is dangerous. Instead look at what Intel says

According to a document from Intel:

> In order to effectively write your code to take advantage of these
>   rules, when writing if-else or switch statements, check the most
>   common cases first and work progressively down to the least common.

Comment: On your postfix vs. prefix increment comment, note that `If the operand is a built-in type, such as int, then the two are equivalent`. So in this case, it makes no difference.

Comment: @SRF Thanks for your reply and the suggestion about 'x++', but the ints can change randomly!